# MySQL select record from one table there not exist in othre

Tags: mysql, select, not-exists

I have 2 tables:

```
TABLE customer_service_provider
==================================
id   | customer | service_provider
==================================
1    | 1        | 1
2    | 1        | 2
3    | 1        | 3
4    | 2        | 1
5    | 2        | 2
6    | 3        | 1
7    | 4        | 1
8    | 4        | 2
9    | 4        | 3
===================================

TABLE service_provider
======================
id     | Name
======================
1      | Company1
2      | Company2
3      | Company3
======================
```

I need to get info from table `customer_service_provider` (fields `customer` and `service_provider`) which `service_provider` not exists in table `customer_service_provider`, but exist in `service_provider` table.

The result should look like:

```
customer   |  service_provider
==============================
2          | 3
3          | 2
3          | 3
==============================
```

## SOLVED:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT sp.id,
    csp.customer
FROM
    service_provider sp,
    customer_service_provider csp
WHERE
    sp.id NOT IN( SELECT csp2.service_provider 
                  FROM customer_service_provider csp2 
                  WHERE csp2.customer = csp.customer)
```

Comment: I don't get it. You want what exactly?

Comment: you do have service_provider `1, 2, 3` in `customer_service_provider`... so by your requirement, you should have *no* output

Comment: Don't put a giant "SOLVED" section. Either accept an answer below that solved your problem, or if you did it yourself, post an answer and mark that as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.customer, s.id
FROM customer_service_provider c, service_provider s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM customer_service_provider c2
    WHERE c2.customer = c.customer AND c2.service_provider = s.id
)
```

Or, more efficient:

```
SELECT c.customer, s.id
FROM customer_service_provider c, service_provider s
LEFT OUTER JOIN customer_service_provider c2 ON c2.customer = c.customer AND c2.service_provider = s.id
WHERE c2.id IS NULL
```

I've not tested it, let me know.

Comment: The query executes forever and just hangs with no result. C tables has about 16k records, S table has only 10 so very huge loop comes.

Comment: Ok, I did not considered table size. I try to rewrite a more efficient version.

Comment: sorry for such delay, but it doesnt work:[SQL] SELECT c.customer, s.id
FROM customer_service_provider c, service_provider s
LEFT OUTER JOIN customer_service_provider c2 ON c2.customer = c.customer AND c2.service_provider = s.id
WHERE c2.id IS NULL

[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'c.customer' in 'on clause'                  interesting thing is that, the column exists, but throws that kind of error, I have tried to rewrite it in several ways, but it didnt help.

Comment: the first query works perfectly, just need to add DISTINCT, and the **MOST** important thing which I have forgot was, to add index into table, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I presume you also have a table with customers. In that case, use the following:

```
select customer.id, service_provider.id 
from customer, service_provider 
left join customer_service_provider on customer.id=customer_service_provider.customer and service_provider.id=customer_service_provider.service_provider
where customer_service_provider.id IS NULL;
```

Basically, return all combinations of customers and service providers. Do a `LEFT JOIN` of this on the customer_service_provider table; and only keep things where there is no matching record.

Comment: The following query:
`SELECT 
 add_customers.id, 
 service_provider.id 
FROM 
 add_customers, 
 service_provider  
 LEFT JOIN customer_service_provider ON add_customers.id=customer_service_provider.customer AND service_provider.id=customer_service_provider.service_provider
WHERE 
 customer_service_provider.id IS NULL`

Returns this error: **1054 - Unknown column 'add_customers.id' in 'on clause'**

Comment: Hi Arturas, what is the name of the id field in your table 'add_customers' ??

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT sp.id,
    csp.customer
FROM
    service_provider sp,
    customer_service_provider csp
WHERE
    sp.id NOT IN( SELECT csp2.service_provider 
                  FROM customer_service_provider csp2 
                  WHERE csp2.customer = csp.customer)
```